# Mercurial Clone Does not appear to be an hg repository (no content-type)

Tags: version-control, mercurial, clone, tortoisehg

When trying to clone a mercurial repository I get the following error...

```
sending getbundlecommand
requested url: 'http://hg/myrepo/?cmd=getbundle'
abort: 'http://hg/myrepo' does not appear to be an hg repository:
---%<--- (no content-type)
---%<---
!
```

Initially I was getting a 400 bad request response which was seemingly to do with exceeding the MaxFieldLength and MaxRequestBytes limits which I have now set to maximum as suggested on Mercurial wiki ([7.1 I'm getting an HTTP 400: Bad request error. What's going on?](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebInIisOnWindows#I.27m_getting_an_HTTP_400:_Bad_request_error._What.27s_going_on.3F)).

Now I get the no content-type error. I have found a few similar threads on the bitbucket site and in various places but no concrete solutions. I haven't configured any plugins/extensions/hooks on that repo and I know that the webserver is serving up repo's correctly as I'm able to clone all other repos without a problem. This is the largest repo we have and think the number of branches, heads and commits must somehow be related.

Hoping someone has come accross this before and can point me in the right direction!?

Comment: Have you been able to clone from the exact same URL before, or can you clone from other machines from the exact same URL now?  "getbundle" seems odd, are you sure you've input the right URL?

Comment: How/where are you hosting the repository you're trying to clone from?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I personally have never cloned from that url before but it's an old repo and someone may have done in the past. Anyone cloning it now generally uses the UNC path as it is on the same network as the machines that are cloning it. The problem has arisen because we have introduced Upsource by jetbrains as a code review tool and this requires a http path to clone from.

Comment: with regards the url i am just giving it http://hg/myrepo, you can see the ?cmd=getbundle because I have the --debug --verbose flags on.

Comment: Which mercurial server do you have running there?

Comment: I think it's just a windows server with hgwebdir?